# NetStream.seek is causing my video to stop

Tags: actionscript-3, netstream, akamai

My video plays just fine. If I do a `netStream.seek(0)` that works fine. If I so much as `netStream.seek(1)` then my stream finishes on the spot and stops back to zero.

However, if I play my file in http://support.akamai.com/flash/ then it scrubs just fine. That particular player is using the OVP framework whereas I'm using the Akamai HD Core framework which is based on the OVP framework so I don't understand why this is happening.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thanks.

PS - a url for testing is rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mediapm/strobe/content/test/SpaceAloneHD_sounas_640_500_short

code from top to bottom (one-stop fla)

```
import com.akamai.display.AkamaiMediaSprite;
import org.openvideoplayer.events.OvpEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.net.NetStream;

var s:AkamaiMediaSprite = new AkamaiMediaSprite(this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);

this.addChild(s);

//
s.load("rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mediapm/strobe/content/test/SpaceAloneHD_sounas_640_500_short");
s.addEventListener(OvpEvent.LOADED, playerLoadedHandler);

function playerLoadedHandler(event:OvpEvent):void {
    var ns:NetStream = s.netStream;
    ns.addEventListener(OvpEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
}

function mouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(s.netStream.time);
    //s.netStream.seek(0);
    s.netStream.seek(1);
}

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    trace("!! net status: ", event.info.code);
}

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
```

Comment: show the code where you load, play and seek the video.  Then we can prob help you

Comment: it's a small swf, so I dropped all the code in there.

Comment: so here is what I think is happening. seek() goes to the "nearest keyframe" to the position you requested.  Maybe the nearest keyframe to 1 IS 0 so it is behaving as expected.  Try netStream.seek(30) and see what you get. As a side note, you status listener should say (NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler)... it is accidentally working because OvpEvent.NET_STATUS luckily has the same string value... but NetStream is actually dispatching a NetStatusEvent... not an OvpEvent.